# Drag Handeler unreconized console Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

i have a problem with my code , the "DragHandeler" is not reconized by Visual Studio , but when i look tutorial , it works . I dont know why it dont work for me . The console say " Drag Handeler doesn't exist in this context" . 
If you know how to resolve this , pls let me know ! 
Sorry for my english.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public GameObject item
    {
        get
        {
            if (transform.childCount > 0)
            {
                return transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    #region IDropHandler implementation

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (!item)
        {
            DragHandeler.itemBeingDraged.transform.SetParent(transform);

        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: `DragHandeler` does not exit. Are you following a tutorial or something? Where did you get that code from? It seems like a bad copy and paste to me

Comment: I said it , i'm following tutorials , and in the tutorial , it works , and Unity reconized DragHandeler :/ That's the video i follow , and its at 13:58      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c47QYgsJrWc

Comment: *"but when i look tutorial , it works"*.... That's what you said which doesn't really make sense. That's a simple tutorial. Don't skip any part of the video. Start over again and watch it till end and you'll realize that you have to create a script named `DragHandeler`.

Comment: You should start with the official tutorials first and when you know unity at least at advanced level, check other more specific tutorials

Comment: @molikayess He creates the `DragHandler` script at 5:30 in the youtube video you linked. You probably skipped this step.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just started following a tutorial, skipped some steps, and can't resolve their issues.

Comment: Guys , i wrote the code named "Drag Handeler" , i've all of scprits he wrote before this problem , when he wrote again "Drag Handeler" , i've this in the console : "The name DragHandeler does not exist in the current context"